# GetEntryAssembly doesn't appear to work when the entry assembly is ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, reflection, .net-assembly

First, I do not believe this is a dupe of these:

[GetEntryAssembly for web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277692/getentryassembly-for-web-applications)

[Get entry assembly from ASP.NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740083/get-entry-assembly-from-asp-net-application)

I have an ASP.NET WebForms app that references a class library.  When I call `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` from within the class library while it's referenced by the ASP.NET app, it returns null.  However, when I call that same code while the class library is referenced by a console app, it returns the console app assembly.

This answer perhaps sheds light on why `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` behaves differently with ASP.NET:

[Why do ASP.NET resolve assembly references differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025633/why-do-asp-net-resolve-assembly-references-differently)

Still, I'd like to be able to get the ASP.NET assembly as if it were a Windows application (console, WPF, WinForms, etc).  Is there any way to allow my class library to know about the ASP.NET assembly without adding any ASP.NET references?

**Edit:**  While not the solution I am looking for, this works for the time being.  Basically, I use the code below provided by the answerer from one of the questions above to get the ASP.NET assembly from *within* the web app and then pass it as an argument to a method in my class library.

There's also `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` which does expose the ASP.NET assembly when called within the class library, but there are like 50 assemblies loaded in the app domain which means you'd need a magic string to get the assembly name.  Definitely not an option, but it could work.

```
static private Assembly GetWebEntryAssembly()
{
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current == null ||
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance == null) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    var type = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.GetType();
    while (type != null && type.Namespace == "ASP") {
        type = type.BaseType;
    }

    return type == null ? null : type.Assembly;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An ASP.NET application is started by IIS worker process, which is a native module, in most cases. Thus, that API should return `null` to reflect the differences from a console application.

Whatever you want to achieve with that API, find an alternative way instead.